Ubuntu 24.04 and .pxarexclude-cli
I just installed a new Ubuntu 24.04.1 and I wonder what this file .pxarexclude-cli in the root directory is good for.
This is its contents:
/tmp/?*
/var/tmp/?*
/var/run/?*.pid
lost+found


It is the config file for tool called "proxmox backup". That file contains the globs you added to the command to create an archive.
Typically it looks like this:
 pxar create archive.pxar /path/to/source --exclude '/tmp/?*'

and that file will hold /tmp/?*.
